# SQL Server: How to use a database name as a parameter in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I do a join on tables of 2 different `db` in same `domain` like

```
SET DBname = "sample"
SELECT *
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN DBname.Table2 T On Table1.key = T.Key
```

Its reporting like

> Invalid column name T

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You cannot store object identifiers in variables and use them in a query, you would need to use dynamic SQL instead. For databases on the same server the syntax is `select * from databasename.schemaname.tablename` for databases on a different server use `sp_addlinkedserver` and `select * from servername.databasename.schemaname.tablename`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use dynamic sql:

```
@DBname = 'sample';
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = '
SELECT *
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN
     @DBname.table2
     On Table1.key = Table2.Key';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@DBname', @DBname);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Databases in general -- and SQL Server in particular -- do not allow parameters to represent database names, schema names, table names, or column names.

Comment: I understand . But I have only IDs whose name are in a different DB. Either I need to copy the names as well to my ID or do what i am doing now