# SqlConnectionCommand ( CREATE DATABASE)

Tags: sql-server, sqlconnection

Does anyone know why the first code works but the second does not?
At the second I get exception (wrong syntax near @databaseName).

First Code

```
public void CreateDatabase(string databaseName)
{
     string command = "CREATE DATABASE " + databaseName;
     using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionStringBuilder.ToString()))
     {
          sqlConn.Open();
          using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(command, sqlConn))
          {
               sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
          }
     }
}
```

Second Code

```
public void CreateDatabase(string databaseName)
{
     string command = "CREATE DATABASE @databaseName";   \\I tried both
     string command = "CREATE DATABASE '@databaseName'";  \\I tried both
     using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionStringBuilder.ToString()))
     {
          sqlConn.Open();
          using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(command, sqlConn))
          {
               sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@"databaseName", databaseName));
               sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Because you can't use a parameter for a ddl statement. Why do you need to create a database in your application anyway?

Comment: thank you. because I am currently learning MVVM and would like to write a sample program

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: How to use a database name as a parameter in a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400262/sql-server-how-to-use-a-database-name-as-a-parameter-in-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: Not sure why that requires you to constantly need more databases but I will just pass that as a different discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TSQL the general rule is you can't parameterize Data Definition Language (DDL) statements at all.  And you can't use parameters in place of identifiers in Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements.