# Creating table of DB and table info on SQL Server Instance using while loop

Tags: sql-server, variables, while-loop

I was wondering why i can't substitute the DB name for the variable @DBNAME in the following while loop:

I can use the variable as the DB_NAME but it wont let me substitute the DB name for sys.tables

it is giving me the following error: Incorrect syntax near '.'.

```
DROP TABLE #TABLE_INFO;
CREATE TABLE #TABLE_INFO
    (
    DB_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    CREATE_DATE DATE
    );

DECLARE @COUNT AS INT = 1
DECLARE @DBNAME AS VARCHAR(100)

WHILE @COUNT < (SELECT MAX(DATABASE_ID) +1 FROM SYS.DATABASES)
BEGIN
    SET @DBNAME = (SELECT NAME FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE DATABASE_ID = @COUNT)

    INSERT INTO #TABLE_INFO
    SELECT
        @DBNAME AS DB_NAME,
        A1.NAME AS TABLE_NAME,
        A1.CREATE_DATE
    FROM @DBNAME.SYS.TABLES A1

    SET @COUNT = @COUNT+1
END

SELECT * FROM #TABLE_INFO;
```

Comment: T-SQL does not support parameterization of database object identifiers (database names, table names, column names, etc), only values may be parameterised. I'm not aware of any SQL dialect that allows parameterization of database object identifiers, actually. The only workaround to this is to use Dynamic SQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server: How to use a database name as a parameter in a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400262/sql-server-how-to-use-a-database-name-as-a-parameter-in-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- T-SQL does not allow database object-identifiers to be parameteried.

  - ...So you **have** to use Dynamic SQL (i.e. building up a query inside a string value and passing it to `sp_executesql`).
  - Obviously this is dangerous due to the risk of SQL injection, or simply forgetting to escape names correctly (use `QUOTENAME`) which may cause inadvertent data-loss (e.g. if someone actually named a table as `[DELETE FROM Users]`).
  - So it's important to use Dynamic SQL as little as possible.
  - What you can do is use `INSERT INTO @tableVariable EXECUTE sp_executesql @query` which allows you to store the results of a stored procedure - or any dynamic SQL - into a table-variable or temporary-table without them being output directly to your client connection and then process the results using non-dynamic SQL.
  - You can also use `CROSS APPLY` too if you can move all of your dynamic-SQL logic to a stored-procedure.

Try this:

- BTW, I changed your `WHILE` loop to use a `STATIC READ_ONNLY CURSOR`  which avoids your assumptions about how `sys.databases`'s `database_id` work (e.g. what if `sys.databases` lists only these 4 `database_id` values `1, 2, 99997, 99998`? Your `WHILE` loop would be wasting time checking for `3, 4, 5, 6, ..., 99996`).
- I also use a table-variable rather than a temporary-table because the scope and lifetime of a table-variable is easier to reason about compared to a temporary-table. That said, there aren't really any performance benefits of TVs over TTs (though you can pass TVs as table-valued-parameters, which is nice and generally much better than passing data to sprocs using TTs).

```
DECLARE @results TABLE (
    DatabaseName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    SchemaName   nvarchar(50)  NOT NULL,
    TableName    nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Created      datetime      NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @dbName nvarchar(100);

DECLARE c CURSOR STATIC READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT QUOTENAME( [name] ) FROM sys.databases;

OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @dbName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @dbQuery nvarchar(1000) = N'

SELECT
    ''' + @dbName + N''' AS DatabaseName,
    s.[name]      AS SchemaName,
    t.[name]      AS TableName,
    t.create_date AS Created
FROM
    ' + @dbName + N'.sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
ORDER BY
    s.[name],
    t.[name]
';

    INSERT INTO @results
        ( DatabaseName, SchemaName, TableName, Created )
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @dbQuery;
    
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @dbName;
    
END;
CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;

--------------------------

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @results
ORDER BY
    DatabaseName,
    SchemaName,
    TableName;
```

I am able to copy+paste this query into SSMS and run it against my SQL Server 2017 box without modifications and it returns the expected results.

Comment: Thank you Dai, this second answer is exactly the result i wanted and the first suggestion gave me some background on the issue i was having. Much appreciated!